# Matrix determinant lemma proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The Matrix determinant lemma states that

$\det(A + uv^T) = det(A)(1 + v^T(A^{-1}u))$

However, I do not understand how do we get the second multiplier here. I was kind of able to understand [this proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) on wiki right up until the moment where we go from $\det(I + (A^{-1}u)v^T)$ to the multiplier in question. How do we understand that the value of the determinant $\det(I + (A^{-1}u)v^T)$ is $(1 + v^T(A^{-1}u))$? It's not like we know a general formula for the determinant of sum of the identity and something else (or do we? didn't find it)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The wiki have shown the answer, for by $\det (AB)=(\det A)(\det B)$, $\det(I + (A^{-1}u)v^T)$ is also the determinant of 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0\\
v^T & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
I+uv^T & u\\
0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0\\
-v^T & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
I & u\\
0 & 1+v^Tu\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
where the determinant of RHS is what you want.